# Using Akka actors to invoke or pass messages to Python code

Tags: python, scala, akka, actor, pykka

I've a some analysis code that's written in Python. Currently I'm using Storm to process streams. Because Storm allows invocation of python code using message serialization I an invoke Python code from Java/Scala in my Storm bolts.

I found [Pykka](http://www.pykka.org/en/latest/) which is a Python implementation of the actor model. I was wondering if there is a way to invoke Python code from Akka actors? For example, is it possible to pass message from Akka actors to Pykka actors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that the wire protocols for the two remote actor model implementations could be easily bridged, but you could use [0MQ](http://zeromq.org/) between the Scala code and a Python app.  Akka allows [message passing over 0MQ](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/zeromq.html), so after some setup the Scala code could deal with the Python app just like any other actor, although I'm not sure what that would mean on the Python side.

Another possibility worth considering is to run your Python analysis code on the JVM using [Jython](http://www.jython.org/).  You could have a Scala actor call a Jython function/method.  But if your Python code makes use of C extension modules, you'd have to find alternatives.

Yet another possibility (also assuming you aren't using C extension modules) is to give the converter [py2scala](https://code.google.com/p/py2scala/) a try; for data analysis code it might do a decent job.  Presumably this would give you the most performant solution.

Comment: Would you please give a word here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665037/concurrency-advanced-python-and-interaction-with-different-objects

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`Jep`](https://github.com/ninia/jep) to run embedded `CPython` in the actor JVM for full access to the native (C) `Python` packages.

See slide 5 here [Mixing Python and Java](https://www.slideshare.net/onyame/mixing-python-and-java).

If Python packages you need are not thread safe then can use remote `Akka` actors.
See https://github.com/alpinedatalabs/alpine-r/blob/35209af47f896450e4f8f8745a80595d01035ca3/server/src/main/resources/application.conf#L4

To make the `Scala` to `Python` smoother try [`ScalaPy`](https://github.com/shadaj/scalapy) - also built on top of `Jep`.

Technically something similar should also work for R using [`Renjin`](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin) - `GPL`, unfortunately so must be careful with running embedded.